# WrapPanel get First child element when resizing

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, resize, wrappanel

I have a user control **PianoScore** and it has `WrapPanel` in order to display many bars.
For example, here is a piano score with 8 bars.

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <WrapPanel Name="WrapPanel_Bars" Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <local:BarRenderer></local:BarRenderer>
        <local:BarRenderer></local:BarRenderer>
        <local:BarRenderer></local:BarRenderer>
        <local:BarRenderer></local:BarRenderer>
        <local:BarRenderer></local:BarRenderer>
        <local:BarRenderer></local:BarRenderer>
        <local:BarRenderer></local:BarRenderer>
        <local:BarRenderer></local:BarRenderer>
    </WrapPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

And the thing is, whenever the `WrapPanel_Bars` gets resized, I need to add a **Treble Clef** and **Bass Clef** to every first bar element of the line.

I'm looking for some callback methods for example:

```
private void WrapPanel_Bars_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
        var renderers[] = /* How can I get every first BarRenderer of WrapPanel??? */
        foreach (var renderer in renderers)
        {
            // Set renderer's clefs
            renderer.UpClef = Clefs.Treble;
            renderer.DownClef = Clefs.Bass;
        }
}
```

Expected result:

Sorting `BarRenderers` by 3
[image]

Sorting `BarRenderers` by 2
[image]

I appreciate any kind of your help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Get 'sender as WrapPanel' in the handler method and iterate its Children property while casting each child to BarRenderer.

Comment: I know that I need to get sender as WrapPanel, but how can I know the number of child controls which WrapPanel includes in one row?

Comment: You do not receive this information from WrapPanel.
You could use TransaformToAncestor to calculate this for each child:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-get-the-offset-of-a-visual